# How to translate game difficulty level terminology: "noob level", "mature level", "mad level"

Tags: translation

I have a game that has 3 levels of difficulty: "noob level", mature level", "mad level". How can I translate these 3 terms into Chinese? (I don't use "easy", "normal", "hard" in my game because they are popular and trivial words. I want to use some 'special words')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noob level - 菜鸟级别
Mature level - 成熟级别
Mad level - 疯狂级别

You might want to wait for some other answers as people here are creative~

Comment: I would translate as Mature level - 熟手级别

Comment: @user3919509 is this Simplified or Traditional or both?

Comment: for the answer, it's simplified.  For 熟手级别, it's both

Answer (score 2):

noob level

新手級

mature level

熟手級

mad level

師傅級

Comment: I think 師傅 is a little too formal for the OP intentions...

Comment: 師傅級 would be 'master level', sounds good but it explicity asked for the translation for 'mad level'

Answer (score 1):

Noob level: (新手 / 入門 / 菜鳥) + (級 / 級別 / 模式)

Mature level: (高手 / 達人) + (級 / 級別 / 模式)

Mad level: 瘋狂模式 / 地獄模式 / 大師級(級別)

Not sure these translates are nature in Mainland, I'm a Taiwanese.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see is this creative for you, it's kind of buzzword in the web, it's a bit rude does not meant for offend.

Noob level - 智障/脑残/手残/草泥马/屌丝级别 Intellectual disability/Brain Disfunction/Hand Disfunction/Grass Mud Horse or dump/nobody or loser.

Mature level -  普通级别 Just normal, nothing special I can think of.

Mad level - 爱因斯坦/牛顿级别 Albert Einstein/Newton, or any other famous geek that related to your game. Some other great translation would be 牛逼/神马/高富帅(男)/白富美(女)）级别 stunning or Holy shit(the closest I can think of)/God Horse/Tall Rich Handsome(Male)/white rich pretty(Female)